# R: argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA and cannot pass the column name as argument

Tags: r

The function I created below is reading 332 files from directory to data_frame.
The files all have the same column, such as "nitrate". When I pass the argument "nitrate" to the function there is a error as below

```
Warning message:
In mean.default(data_frame$pollutant, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

The function is:

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory,pollutant,id = 1:332) {
    ##set up directory
    file_names <-
        dir(paste("C:/Users/Bruce/Desktop",directory,sep = "/"))

    ## red files according to the id
    data_frame <- do.call(rbind, lapply(file_names[id], read.csv))

    ## get the mean

    mean(data_frame$pollutant, na.rm = TRUE)

}
```

call the Function and pass the argument

```
pollutantmean("specdata","nitrate",1:10)
```

However, when I change the function, as below:

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory,pollutant,id = 1:332) {
    ##set up directory
    file_names <-
        dir(paste("C:/Users/Bruce/Desktop",directory,sep = "/"))

    ## red files according to the id
    data_frame <- do.call(rbind, lapply(file_names[id], read.csv))
    data_frame
    ## get the mean
      if(pollutant == "nitrate"){
          mean(data_frame$nitrate, na.rm = TRUE)
      }else if(pollutant == "sulfate"){
          mean(data_frame$sulfate, na.rm = TRUE)
      }


}
```

It works. I want to know the reason why it cannot work when I pass "nitrate" in the first function.

Comment: The index 332 and the name "pollutant" are rather suspicious (actually more than suspicious) for an online course on R. There are tons of other questions asked and answered on this homework set. Why not a) admit that you are asking us to give you advice about your homework, and b) do some searching BEFORE posting?

Answer (score 1):

`data_frame$pollutant` looks for a column named `pollutant`. To access a column using a variable name `pollutant`, you need to use `data_frame[,pollutant]`